# How to find $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2)\right|$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

How to find $\left|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2)\right|=?$

Since $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has 4 elements, $1 \leq \left|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2)\right|\leq \left|S_4\right|$.

How to proceed further?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hint: Since an automorphism must fix the identity, you can do a little better (and then check that all of the ones you get happen to be automorphisms).

Comment: @DerekHolt Why did you close this question?

Comment: For the reason stated: the question has already been answered in detail in an earlier post. Presumably you disagree - can you explain why?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that in $(\mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z)$ all elements besides the neutral have order two (and each of them is just the product of the other two!), so every automorphisms "permutes" them and maps the neutral element to itself.

We have therefore shown something stronger: $\textrm{Aut} (\mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z) \cong S_3$.

Comment: You have not quite argued that all the permutations are actually automorphisms.

Comment: We know that $e$ must be fixed, so there are at most $6$ automorphisms. Can't I define $S_3$ as group of permutations of $\{(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)\}$?

Comment: Yes, but it is a bit of a coincidence that all of those permutations are actually automorphisms.

Comment: For more on this phenomenon, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452596/is-a-bijection-from-a-group-to-itself-automatically-an-isomorphism-if-it-maps-th/