# Is a bijective map between two groups always an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Does a bijective map between two groups always produce an isomorphism?

I am trying to find a bijective map between two groups which does not preserve the group operations.

I have found a bijection $f(g)=g^3$, where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, 
defined by $f(g+h)=(g+h)^3$.

But $f(g + h) \neq     $
$ f(g)+f(h) \\=g^3+h^3$

Comment: $f:\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z_2: 0\mapsto 1, 1\mapsto 0$.

Comment: by its definition, an isomorphism is a "homomorphism" which is bijective..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Actually, not by its definition. That's a theorem. A theorem which is untrue in other concrete categories :)

Comment: I do not know about categories... at least in Group theory, I learned that an isomorphism is a homomorphism which is a bijection....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Technically it's defined to be a homomorphism which is invertible, with inverse also a homomorphism. It's a theorem that if f is bijective its inverse is automatically a homomorhpism, but this isn't the definition (or at least not the right definition).

Comment: @AlexYoucis : yes, yes.. It seem to be true.. :) :)

Comment: @Astrolink The map you give is *not* a bijection. What is mapped to $2\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Astrolink Your edit now means that you have answered your own question! You have found a bijection between groups which is *not* a homomorphism, although it does preserve the identity (and so it is closer to Tobias' answer than to azimut's and walcher's ones, where they shift the identity).

Comment: @Alex, will you please provide a reference to a bijective morphism which fails to meet this criterion (it can certainly be textbook; I obviously am new to this)?

Comment: @JonathanY. There are lots of examples. The map $\mathbb{A}^1\to V(y^2-x^3)$ defined by $t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ is a bijective morphism of varieties, but not an isomorphism (it certainly can't be by smoothness issues), the map $X\to Y:x\mapsto x$ where $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is continuous and bijective, but not an isomorphism, etc.

Answer (score 6):

For a group $G$ with $\lvert G\rvert > 1$, we can find a bijection from $G
\to G$ that's  not a homomorphism.

Since the order of $G$ is at least $2$, there is a $g\in G$ with $g\neq 1_G$.

Now the map $f_g : G \to G$
$$
f_g : x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
g & \text{if } x = 1_G,\\
1_G & \text{if }x = g,\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is a bijection, but not a homomorphism (since $f_g(1_G) \neq 1_G$).

Comment: (I changed $f\mapsto f_g$, as I think it makes it neater. I hope you don't mind my being so bold. I won't be offended if you undo it.)

Comment: @user1729: Why did you change it to $f_g$? I'm confounded.

Comment: @FrankMuer It was 6 months ago! I think it was because the function is dependent on the element $g$.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, there are a few groups where any bijective map from the group to itself which preserves the identity element are automorphisms (ie, isomorphisms of the group with itself).

These groups are precisely $\{1\}$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

It is easy to check that these groups satisfy the above property, and that these are the only ones follows from my answer at [Is a Bijection From a Group to Itself Automatically an Isomorphism If It Maps the Identity to Itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452596/is-a-bijection-from-a-group-to-itself-automatically-an-isomorphism-if-it-maps-th/452609#452609)

Comment: See also the answers in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108923/upper-bounds-on-the-size-of-operatornameautg/).

Answer (score 4):

This is by means of azimut's answer. Black is group G. Orange is x.

[image]

Comment: Nice illustration of the idea.

Answer (score 3):

A maybe more "natural" example is the following map: if $G$ is not trivial, pick $g\in G,g\neq 1_G$.

Then the map $$\ell_g:x\in G\mapsto gx\in G$$ is bijective (with inverse $\ell_{g^{-1}}$), but not a group homomorphism, since $g=f(1_G)=f(1_G ^2)\neq f(1_G)^2=g^2$ (otherwise, by simplification by $g$, we would have $g=1_G$)